# trying to execute shell script command as sudo from jenkins and I get below error, not sure what's causing it

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, sudo

In Jenkins call to the the script

```
ssh -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no someuser@10.180.129.187  "sudo /home/ram/bin/setup.sh"
```

this is the debug message :

```
+ ssh -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.180.129.187 'sudo /home/ram/bin/setup.sh'
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.190.128.193 [10.190.128.193] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ram/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ram/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ram/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ram/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ram/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ram/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ram/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ram/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 960 bytes for a total of 981
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 1005
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 129/256
debug2: bits set: 490/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1149
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 10.190.128.193 filename /home/ram/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 10.190.128.193 filename /home/ram/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 5
debug1: Host '10.190.128.193' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ram/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug2: bits set: 490/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1165
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1213
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/ram/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ram/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ram/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ram/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1277
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 10.190.128.193.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_5667' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_5667' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_5667' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ram/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/ram/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ram/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ram/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ram/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ram/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ram/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ram/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 49 padlen 15 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1421
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 49 padlen 15 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1565
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 49 padlen 15 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1709
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
 Help us localize this page
```

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/tty` show?

Comment: crw-rw-rw- l  root tty 5

Comment: Is the server you are trying to access protected by a password or by a RSA secret/key or by something else?

Comment: should be by password..although am not sure

Comment: Please check it.

Comment: am not sure how to check this.. I could log into the server manually using root username and password

Comment: Connect to the server manually by using ssh directly and if you can log in with a password, your server uses a password.

Comment: I can login into the server using putty..yes, my server uses a password

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

It's not working because the server requires a password for authentication, but ssh gets executed by Jenkins and therefore ssh's stdin is connected to Jenkins and not to your terminal and so it is not possible for ssh to ask for the password.You need to configure the server to accept RSA-key-based authentication so that you can give ssh the key to be able to authenticate without user interaction.

### How to use a RSA-keypair for authentication:

1. Open a terminal on your local computer
2. Execute `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, for the location simply press enter and for the password simply press enter too.
3. Execute `ssh-copy-id yourremoteuser@1.2.3.4` (replace "yourremoteuser@1.2.3.4" with your remote username and server ip address)
4. Answer the sure you want to connect question with yes.
5. Enter the password of your server.
6. Now you can use your RSA key to login to the server.

Comment: I have followed all the step and created rsa key...Still, I get the same error.Is it something I need to add the command to pick up the rsa key to login into the server?

Comment: Can you login without password by executing `ssh yourremoteuser@1.2.3.4`?

Comment: Nope!..looking into /var/log/secure shows failed password for user from 1.2.3.4  port 1234 ssh2

Comment: Did you execute the `ssh-keygen` command under the same user as you used for executing `ssh yourremoteuser@1.2.3.4`?

Comment: What's the output of `ls /home/yourremoteuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` on your server?

Comment: yes.. I could see three keys present at the end it has username@xyz.com.Username is the same username as what am trying to ssh..

Comment: What's in the "/home/yourremoteuser/.ssh/" folder?

Comment: I don't have /home/root/.ssh.. root user folder is not present

Comment: Where did you store the private key then?

Comment: I think you just asked to press enter.. might be in default location.. I can see some keys in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant what is in the "/home/yourlocaluser/.ssh" folder on your local computer.

Comment: I don't see any such file.. my local computer is in windows 10.. I also have an entry in sudoers file.. ALL  ALL= (ALL) NOPASSWD: /location to script.. still looks like it is using password authentication from looking at /va/log/secure logs

Comment: On the computer where you created the keypair should be a file called "id_rsa" in the folder "~/.ssh/" and on the server you try to ssh into should be a file called "id_rsa.pub" in the "~/.ssh/authorized_keys/" folder.Also make sure that the "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" file on the server you are trying to ssh into contains the following: `RSAAuthentication yes(newline)PubkeyAuthentication yes(newline)AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys(newline)` (the "(newline)" needs to be replaced with a real new line character)

Comment: Am sorry, I never created key pair in my computer. I created all the above steps in my server. The point I don't understand is why the key in my local computer shold match the key in the server. what if suppose someone tries to run this Jenkins job and that person doesn't have a key to match server key.

Comment: Your Jenkins job is running on server A and it tries to connect via ssh to server/computer B, right?So what's exactly computer B, another server?I think I got a little bit confused, sorry.

Comment: Nope, My jenkins job is running in one server and the shell script is also present in the same machine.Am trying to trigger the script from jenkins job which requires username/password since the shell script has sudo commands

Comment: Than for what does the script use ssh???

Comment: It still needs to run the script.. I was able to run the script using ssh plugin and in build step, there is step 'execute schell script on remote using ssh'